# Grabbing hidden code (Using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser)

Tags: php, html, parsing, html-parsing

I have the following HTML code. I need to grab the code contained in the div container, but the problem is that parsing HTML with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser I can't grab it because aria-hidden is true. How can I get it?

```
<div class="ui-collapsible-content"  aria-hidden="true">
text here
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue has nothing to do with the `aria-hidden` attribute. Finding an element works if it's hidden or not and despite any attribute.

```
<?php

require_once "./simple_html_dom.php";

$html = '<div class="ui-collapsible-content" aria-hidden="true">text here</div><div class="bye">visible text</div>';
$html = str_get_html($html);

echo $html->find('.ui-collapsible-content', 0)->plaintext; // text here
echo "\n";
echo $html->find('.bye', 0)->plaintext; // visible text
echo "\n";
```